# How can I set the auto_increment start value in Mysql for existing data

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table with 3 rows of data, and I want to add an auto_increment column, I use the following syntax and it works

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD id BIGINT unsigned NOT NULL unique AUTO_INCREMENT
```

but the current rows will get the values like 1,2,3in the newly added auto_increment column.

I instead want those values to be say 1001,1002,1003. IS there a way to do that?

Note I do know that running

```
ALTER TABLE tableA AUTO_INCREMENT=1001
```

would work, but that only works for new rows, not for existing data

Comment: Please see my edit the question referred to only talks about new rows, not existing rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the value with the auto increment keyword to specify a start number.

```
Alter table add column blah int(11) auto increment 10000;
```